# Interpolating values that have very high spread

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

Im trying to interpolate some data to make a smooth curve for some datapoints I have, but interp1d doesn't work with using the x-values I have, it works if I just make a new x-vector being [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], but with original x-values I get some curve that does not fit the data at all.

I am wondering if it's the large span of my x-vector which causes the problems?

My data is this:

```
y = np.array([0.768, 0.901, 1.790, 1.213, 0.543, 0.261, 0.121, 0.049])
x = np.array([1.2e-17, 3.7e-16, 1.2e-14, 2.8e-13, 4.8e-12, 9.2e-11, 2.0e-9, 5.0e-8])
```

Trying interpolation and plotting:

```
xnew = np.linspace(np.min(x),np.max(x),100)
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')
y_smooth=f(xnew)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(xnew, y_smooth)
plt.ylim(0,2)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Gives a figure which doesn't make sense at all. I have googled and searched for a solution for hours now, trying different methods such as curve fitting instead, but nothing seems to work.

Changing the x-data vector, gives the desired curve, but obviously with the wrong x-values:

```
new_x_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

plt.scatter(new_x_data,y)
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the smallest change to your code would be:

```
x = np.log(np.array([1.2e-17, 3.7e-16, 1.2e-14, 2.8e-13, 4.8e-12, 9.2e-11, 2.0e-9, 5.0e-8]))
y = np.array([0.768, 0.901, 1.790, 1.213, 0.543, 0.261, 0.121, 0.049])

xnew = np.linspace(np.min(x),np.max(x),100)
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')
y_smooth=f(xnew)

plt.scatter(np.exp(x), y)
plt.plot(np.exp(xnew), y_smooth)
plt.ylim(0,2)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

which gives me something sensible looking.  note the `log` and `exp`s to move into log space and back out again to make the interpolation consistent with the plot

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, to move in and out of log space, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a matter of a discrepancy in how you are viewing the result.

Try using a logspace instead of a linspace -- it should follow the points better. As is, the vast majority of points in xnew are clustered to the right.

Edit:
This shows what is happening a bit better. It is interpolating between them, it just does not look great.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

y = np.array([0.768, 0.901, 1.790, 1.213, 0.543, 0.261, 0.121, 0.049])
x = np.array([1.2e-17, 3.7e-16, 1.2e-14, 2.8e-13, 4.8e-12, 9.2e-11, 2.0e-9, 5.0e-8])

xnew = np.logspace(-16, -8, 100)
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')
y_smooth=f(xnew)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(xnew, y_smooth)
plt.ylim(0,4)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and tips about logspace, unfortunately it did not help. Could it be a problem of 10^-17 being a too small number for python to handle?

Comment: @Emil another way of looking at this is: you need to make sure the interpolation code is seeing log-transformed values.  "python" is following the maths correctly here, you're just expecting it to do something else

Comment: I added some example code-- the interpolation swings pretty hard up and down. Depending on your application, you could choose to interpolate on (log(x), y), it would just be a wildly different mathematical result.